# Dart vs PHP, PHP way faster compared to Dart (aot)

Tags: php, dart, benchmarking

I started recently learning Dart for server side as I like its syntax and aot concept. I wrote a simple script in both language and seems PHP way faster than Dart generated AOT executable.

Dart Code

```dart
import "dart:io";

main() {
  var i = 0;
  while (true) {
    stdout.write("i = $i\n");
    if (i == 1000000) {
      break
    }
    i++;
  }
}
```

Compiled with:
`dart compile exe file-name.dart`

PHP

```php
<?php
$i = 0;
while (true) {
  print("i = $i\n");
  if ($i === 1000000) {
     break;
  }
  $i++;
```

`php file-name.php`

Performance

[Performance-Image Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TKkt.png)

My question is why PHP is faster by ~50% than Dart?
Even I tried to run the dart first without `measure-command` until I see dart app prints to the screen, then I run php, php still go way faster until it pass the dart printed `i` value

I am not sure if I did something wrong, as I know that AOT compiles to native code and I know this related to IO not computation which might has different impact on the benchmark.

And another question that I could not get the answer in dart.dev website. When compiling dart code to AOT is it going to compile the code to native cpu instructions for instance if I say

```
i = i + 1;
```

will be on x86 or similar

```
add i, 1
```

Comment: The way you're measuring the execution speed of the dart program includes the startup time of the dart runtime that's included in the executable. AOT compiling a dart program to an executable does not only generate machine code for your code, there is still a dart runtime.

Comment: This particular test is putting a *lot* of emphasis on differences in I/O performance, which are not necessarily indicative of performance for other operations.  I have some vague recollection of there being some I/O performance issues with the Dart runtime.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I am not measuring the startup execution, even if I start dart first and then php. php still faster.

Comment: @Waleed I'm not sure what that means. The command you show in your image includes the loading of the dart runtime.

Comment: @Waleed How are you measuring execution time and excluding startup time?

Comment: @jamesdlin Even I tried to run the dart first without measure-command until I see it prints to the screen, then I run php, php still go way faster until it pass the dart printed `i` value

Comment: I too don't understand what that means.  You should try measuring the time within the program itself (e.g. with `Stopwatch` in Dart) and without the `print` statements.

Comment: @jamesdlin the performance noticeable by the bare eyes, let's say dart app prints number in 30000 and php start from 0. PHP reach 100000 even before dart app.

Comment: So you're running this from a shell (on Windows?), printing output into that terminal?  Have you tried redirecting output to a file, or to `/dev/null` or whatever Windows calls it?  Waiting for the terminal to read output and draw on the screen is probably the slowest part, and differences in line vs. full buffering could make a big difference.

Comment: I will try it and update the post